# If $h(x) = (f \circ f)(x)$, find $h'(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the graph of $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ as follows. If $h(x) = (f \circ f)(x)$, find $h'(0)$.
[image]

Option:

A. $\frac{5}{9}$
B. $\frac{6}{9}$
C. $\frac{7}{9}$
D. $\frac{8}{9}$
E. $\frac{9}{9}$

The correct answer is C.

My attempt:

I've tried to multiply $f(x)=(x+2)(x+1)(x-3)= x^3-7x-6$, but the graph is not like in the question, so this is not the equation of function.

$h'(x) = f'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$

$h'(0) = f'(f(0)) \cdot f'(0)$

$h'(0) = f'(1) \cdot f'(0)$

But I don't know the value of $f'(1)$ and $f'(0)$

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deduce the values of $a,b,c,d$ from the graph, then compute $f'(1)$ and $f'(0)$. You're almost there with $(x+2)(x+1)(x-3)$, but don't forget the leading coefficient, $a$. You still have to multiply by a constant to assure $f(0)=1$

Comment: Is $a=-\frac{1}{6}$? So the function is $f(x) = -\frac{1}{6}(x^3-7x-6)$?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.